# Limit of a function with different initial values

Tags: calculus

Suppose $y(t)$ solves: $y'(t) = y^{2} - 1$ and $y(0) = \alpha$

Q: What is the limit as $t$ goes to infinity if $\alpha = 0$? If $\alpha = 2$? If $\alpha = -1$?

Excuse the naive question. I'm guessing it's not too difficult, but when I try to argue geometrically, I can't see how the value $y$ takes at $t = 0$ tells us about the limit at infinity, since the equilibrium points are at $1$ and $-1$ and after that the function could either increase *or* decrease, no matter what $y$ at 0 is. Couldn't it?

I'd appreciate if someone gave an answer to this particular problem and a general way to approach these problems, as I am struggling with them.

Comment: You can solve this ODE explicitly using separation of variables. Apply the initial condition and determine the dynamics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. Separate variables and note that the derivative of $-\tanh(x)$ is $\tanh^2(x)-1$. 
Moreover the constant functions $1$ and $-1$ solve the differential equation.

If you are not familiar with hyperbolic functions, by integrating you should find that the general solution (aside from constant solutions $\pm 1$) is
$$y(t)=\frac{1+Ce^{2t}}{1-Ce^{2t}}$$
with $C\not=0$ (which depends on $y(0)=\alpha$.

Note that for $C>0$, $y(t)$ is not defined on the whole real positive half-line.

Are you able to evaluate the limit of $y(t)$ as $t$ goes to infinity for $\alpha = 0,2,-1$?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to talk about qualitative behavior some (as this appears to be your question).  Let's assume we can't solve this easily, and just want to know asymptotics.  We clearly have equilibria at $y = \pm 1$ (as then $y' = 0$).  So, we want to know what will happen in between these equilibria.

If $y = -1-\epsilon$ for $\epsilon>0$, we have that $y' = (-1-\epsilon)^2-1 = 2\epsilon+\epsilon^2$.  So, if $y<-1$, we get that $y'>0$.  We should then expect $\lim_{t\to\infty}y(t) = -1$ if $y(0)<-1$.

If $y = -1+\epsilon$, we can repeat the argument to get that $y' = (-1+\epsilon)^2-1 =-2\epsilon+\epsilon^2 = \epsilon(\epsilon-2)$.  This will be negative for $\epsilon\in(0,2)$, so if $y(0)\in(-1,1)$, we will have $\lim_{t\to\infty}y(t) = -1$ (as the derivative will be negative).

Finally, let $y(0) = 1+\epsilon$.  We get that $y' = (1+\epsilon)^2-1 = 2\epsilon+\epsilon^2$.  We have that the derivative is positive, so $\lim_{t\to\infty}y(t) = \infty$.

Essentially, find where $y' = 0$, and think of these as lines between separate "zones", and then figure out what $y'$ does in each "zone".